# emacs package install error: "autoloading failed to function define-globalized-minor-mode"

Tags: emacs, autoload, evil-mode

I'm trying to install evil-mode for Emacs using the built-in list-packages in Emacs-24. All is well until this:

```
evil-commands.el:29:1:Error: Autoloading failed to define function define-globalized-minor-mode
```

shows up. I haven't been able to find a solution -- I have tried making fresh installs (both from source and by downloading a binary from emacsformacosx.com), since it seems that a function like that probably is a part of Emacs itself.

Any tips/hints are very welcome. I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have an `easy-mmode.el` of your own installed somewhere that would shadow the builtin one?
If not, try to activate `Options => Enter Debugger on Error` in the menu before reproducing the error and show us the backtrace.

Comment: Yes, that was the exact problem -- more specifically, I still had an old ~/.emacs-custom/ folder containing easy-mmode.el in my load-path.

Comment: Same goes for lots of other "standard" files that are typically loaded - sql.el, lisp.el, etc. Don't have files named like that on your load-path.